# Iterating through a Python-provided array one-by-one after user interaction in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*(Bear with me here, I'll attempt to explain this as best I can. Please request clarification if desired.)*

I'm attempting to create a "hot-or-not"-ish type ranker. I have a set of objects given to me via a Django `ValuesQuerySet` and run through `itertools.combinations()` to create pairings. Each pairing is outputted as a tuple of dictionaries, like so:

```
({'id': 55, 'name': u'Person 1'}, {'id': 63, 'name': u'Person 2'}),
({'id': 55, 'name': u'Person 1'}, {'id': 10, 'name': u'Person 3'}),
({'id': 55, 'name': u'Person 1'}, {'id': 90, 'name': u'Person 4'}),
({'id': 63, 'name': u'Person 2'}, {'id': 10, 'name': u'Person 3'}),
... and so on ...
```

I'll be using the rendering the values of these dictionaries in the templates, of course.

The proposed UI for this will display the pictures of each person and await a click from the user. After the click, it'll load the next pairing until all the pairings have been exhausted. 
My JavaScript-fu isn't great at all, so my questions are these:

1. What is the ideal way to feed jQuery a list of tuples of dictionaries to iterate through? JSON? Nested array? Do something with Django?
2. How would one go about iterating through this array one-by-one after a response from the user (rather than just doing a `jQuery.each()` and displaying everything—in addition to providing the opportunity to save a score for the "winning" person to be aggregated once the parings have been exhausted.)?

(Assistance on either or both questions would be greatly appreciated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regarding #1

Without a doubt the best way to get this data from your django view to the javascript in your template is to use `json.dumps()` on your list (of tuples, of dictionaries). The result will be a string that you can pass directly to your template. In the template code, you'd then take that value and assign it to a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// use the 'safe' filter to prevent autoescaping/encoding of potential html entities.
var people = {{ the_json_string|safe }}; // don't forget the semicolon, that would be rude.
// from here, you'll be able to access your data in a natural fashion
console.log(people[0][1].id); // 63
console.log(people[0][1].name); // Person 2

</script>
```

The json module is included in the python stdlib in version 2.6 and up. If you're running an earlier version, I believe django bundles simplejson (a compatible alternative). Don't quote me on this since I don't have a recent django install on my system, but I believe the import path was `from django.utils import simplejson`, and perhaps still is.

### Regarding #2

Making some assumptions here, for the purposes of demonstrating how this could work. Consider the following html fragment (in your template).

```
<div id="hot-or-not">
    <div class="person">
        <span class="name"></span>
        <button>Hot</button>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <span class="name"></span>
        <button>Hot</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

We can take this markup, and reuse it as we proceed through the list of person pairs.
There are a few things to setup to accomplish the UI:

- Setting up event listeners to drive the interactions.
- Adding data to the markup.
- Collecting stats from the user's responses.

Here's my take on how this *could* work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var people = {{ the_json_string|safe }};

function feed_data(){
    if(people.length>0){
        var peeps = people.shift(); // returns the next row off the top of the array
        var divs = $('.people', '#hot-or-not').get(); // returns an array of matching elements
        $.each(peeps, function(i,v){
            $(divs[i]).find('span.name').text(v.name); // set the text for the span
            $(divs[i]).find('button').data('person_id', v.id); // stash the id in the button's "data"
        });
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// initial data fed in
feed_data();

var scores = {}; // we'll keep a map of id => score as we progress.

$('.person>button', '#hot-or-not').on('click', function(){ // note that $(el).on() was introduced recently (1.7.x ?)

    var person_id = $(this).data('person_id'); // we will stash the id in the button when we add our person info to the markup

    if (person_id in scores){
        scores[person_id]++;  // increment this person's score.
    } else {
        scores[person_id] = 1; // this person hasn't been scored yet, so start a new counter.
    }

    var result = feed_data(); // feed in the next set of data (advance to the next pair).
    if(result == false){ // we ran out of people to feed
        // Tally scores here and do whatever you need to do to end the game!
        // There are many ways you could go about searching the object for the highest score...
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to store these pairs of objects in an **array**

```
var people = [[{'id': 55, 'name': u'Person 1'}, {'id': 63, 'name': u'Person 2'}],
              [{'id': 99, 'name': u'Person 3'}, {'id': 10, 'name': u'Person 4'}]];
```

Store the current index you're iterating through, and on each response from the user, load the next pair of people

```
var currentIndex = 0;

function rateNextGroup(index) {
    var nextGroup = people[index];
    $("#personLeftDiv > name").text(nextGroup[0].name);
    $("#personRightDiv > name").text(nextGroup[1].name);
}
```

And then when the user makes his choice:

```
$(".userBtnHotOrNot").click(function() {
    if (currentIndex === people.length - 1)
        alert("You rated the last person!");
    else
        rateNextGroup(++currentIndex);
});
```

If you're wanting to keep track of the score of each person, I would store that right in the people array;

```
$(".userBtnHotOrNot").click(function() {
    var scoreLeft = $("#userScoreLeft").val();
    var scoreRight = $("#userScoreRight").val();

    people[currentIndex][0].userScoreLeft = score;
    people[currentIndex][1].userScoreRight = score;

    if (currentIndex === people.length - 1)
        alert("You rated the last person!");
    else
        rateNextPerson(++currentIndex);
});
```

Which would make finding the most highly rated person trivial:

```
function getHottestPerson(){
    var hottestPerson, currentHighScore = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (people[i][0].userScore > currentHighScore) {
           currentHighScore = people[i][0].userScore;
           hottestPerson = people[i][0]; 
        }
        if (people[i][1].userScore > currentHighScore) {
           currentHighScore = people[i][1].userScore;
           hottestPerson = people[i][1]; 
        }
    }
    alert("Hottest person is " + hottestPerson.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! However, the pairings are important as each is a "battle," ala "Hot-or-Not." I've clarified the example in my question as every person will need to "battle" every other person.

Comment: @BryanVeloso - something like the above should get you started.  I made it an array of object pairs - with each object pair being an array of size 2.